# How to reverse an integer while removing any leading zeroes?

Tags: python

If the input is "0", the output should still be 0.

Example input:

```
-2900
```

Desired output:

```
-92
```

**Question**

Why doesn't my code work?

```
s = input() 
if s.startswith("0"):
    if len(s) != 1:
        s = s.strip("0")
print(int(s[::-1]))
```

Comment: The error message tells you why...

Comment: @Julien Value error? How to handle this...sorry I'm new to Python.

Comment: you probably want to say `s.startswith("-")` to begin with.  there's more work for you to do.

Comment: Before asking **why** it doesn't work, you should show **that** it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = int(input())

sign = 1
if s < 0:
    sign = -1
    s = s * -1

rev = str(s)[::-1]
print(sign * int(rev))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if input starts with "-" so you know if its negative or not
2. if negative remove the leading "-" and make sure to note of it via a variable else do nothing
3. reverse the input
4. cast the reversed input into int making sure to append the sign you got on step 2
5. step 4 will eliminate the leading "0" but will raise error if the input is not a number
6. make sure to have a try-except on step 5
7. return or print the result

Answer (score 0):

It work with your eg.

```
import re

def reverse(number):
    j=''
    for i in str(number):
        if (i!='0') & (i!='-'):
            j=str(i)+j
    if re.findall(r"-", str(number))!=[]:
        print ("-",j)
    else:
        print (j)
```